# Where can the database backup be configured (other than maintance plan and sql jobs)?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2019

There are no maintainance plans or jobs that run sql backups.

But the sql log shows i/o frozen for database, i/o was resumed on database, database backed up, backup database successfully processed x pages.

Where can I look for configured backups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes you can see which software performed a backup by looking in [backupmediaset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/backupmediaset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). There's a column called `software_name` that may hold clues.

You're likely to see something other than `Microsoft SQL Server` here, since native SQL Server backups don't freeze I/O. Someone is probably taking snapshot backups via a tool like Veeam or something, which uses the [Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-vss-writer-backup-guide) to "let SQL Server know" about the backup, which results in the message you are seeing in the log and the corresponding rows in msdb.

These third-party backup tools may be taking a backup at the VM, storage, or database level, but in all cases would be scheduled within the backup software that is performing the backup. If the metadata in `backupmediaset` doesn't help, you'll need to ask around to find out who else is backing up the server or storage and using VSS to snapshot your databases.

Comment: Backup software is Microsoft SQL server

Comment: In msdb.dbo.backupset table, does is_snapshot column value equales 1?  That would confirm the backups are snapshots.

Comment: Where are these scheduled?

Comment: @variable In the application that runs them.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this is due to a fileset, volume level, or VM backup. All of those will use VSS to snapshot the disk. When they do this, they will initiate all of the VSS writers on the box, one of them being the SQL Server Writer. Talk to your backup admin, infrastructure admin, or VM admin to see if they are doing any type of backup. If they are, their action is showing up in your logs.

The message you are seeing in the logs is completely normal and is informational only. You will want to be conscious of these messages in case there are issues and you can correlate them to this time frame. There are cases when these backups run, which are called snapshots, can cause performance issues or service interruptions.

Additionally, if you are taking database backups, you should be confirming that the backups you have are in good working order and contiguous. If those other backups are causing breaks in your log chains, you will speak to the above teams to resolve the issue.